# Bakground image div hiding jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I have a jquery slideshow with captions in div class "feature2". I've add a background image to div class "feature2" that spans 100% width of the screen but the problem is it is hiding my slideshow images - but not their captions?

Below is the page in question:

http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_slideshow.html

And this is an example of how I want it to look - http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_aston.html

If you disable the 'background-image url("Images/background.png")' with firebug it reveals the images behind.

How can I modify this so the image slideshow and captions sit in front of the hatched image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `z-index` to the div tag, so it should look like this:

```
<div class="feature2" style="padding-right: 350.5px; margin-left: -350.5px; padding-left: 350.5px; z-index:1;">
```

`z-index` sets the stack order of specific elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for that - it works! Out of interest, why do I only have to add z-index to that div? I thought I would have to change the z-index of other div's so it knows what order to stack them?

Comment: @DarrenBaker you only have to add it to that specific div cause that is the only one that you needed to put on top.

Comment: Seeing as my answer answered your question, could you be so kind as to "accept it" using the tick button.